# Compare two dataframes and identify difference in new Column

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframes, `a1` and `a2`

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5)
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3)
```

I match and identify the difference by using `semi_join(a1, a2)`

but what I am looking for is something like this
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHmKv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a simple solution of your problem

```
combined <- union(a1, a2)
combined$a1 <- combined$a %in% a1$a
combined$a2 <- combined$a %in% a2$a
```